# Lab power supply to breadboard

Tags: power-supply, breadboard, banana-jack

Recently I purchased a lab power supply, with banana jack output. Are there any specialized products that snap onto the breadboard on which you can connect banana jacks to deliver power to the board?

Any suggestions to products or DIY solutions are appreciated.

I have looked at the MB102 breadboard power supplies, but they use a USB or 2.1mm jack connection to power the board. I am specifically looking to power it from a lab power supply.

Thank you!

Edit: I must add that I have a simple 830 pins breadboard without any binding posts, so I am looking for something like a MB102 module but for banana plugs.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing great.  For breadboards with female bananas binding posts on them, you just run the wire to a bus.

[image: from cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/4/e/b/7/3/518c07b8ce395fea62000001.jpg]
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/4/e/b/7/3/518c07b8ce395fea62000001.jpg

Otherwise, Male banana to test clips are probably the best bet/

[image: from www.apogeekits.com/images/banana_to_grabber_leads.jpg]
from www.apogeekits.com/images/banana_to_grabber_leads.jpg

The latter are not extremely robust arrangements, but solderless breadboard circuits, in general, are not the most robust of prototypes.

Comment: Thank you. It's a pity there is not a commercial solution, but I'll try to fabricate something myself :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've used in the past to robustly connect to a breadboard is to fit a Molex KK connector with locking ramp using superglue. You can then make up a cable from the KK connector to whatever you want at the other end (banana plugs in your case).

You need the superglue otherwise, whenever you try to unplug the cable from the breadboard, the connector comes out instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can get banana leads to alligator clips online. Then also get breadboard pins (also known as PCB pins) which plug into the breadboard.

https://www.jaycar.com.au/0-9mm-pcb-pins-pk-50/p/HP1250

You can then clip the alligators onto those.

Also a good idea if you need leads for an oscilloscope or other equipment which uses BNC plugs. In that case, get BNC to alligator clip leads and use the same method of clipping them onto the gold pcb pins which you plug into the board.

The parrot clips and banana binding posts running to rails mentioned above are also good ideas (might try it myself sometime).

If you want to make up your own leads to avoid breaks in the connections, you can also buy breadboard jumper leads with plugs on both ends, cut off one side and crimp alligator clips on the other ends.

There's many ways to do this, it's just about personal preference and what works best for you. These options give you plugs which go into an individual breadboard socket of course, not any kind of module. Can be useful for op-amp projects when you want to have multiple input values. Hope that helps.